# ruby on rails and css issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I am learning ruby on rails, but I have this problem with my CSS code.

so in `~/Ruby Code/My_Project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyProject</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    :all  %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

and in ~/Ruby Code/My_Project/public/stylesheets I have this, a CSS file called "My_Project.css".

also in ~/Ruby Code/My_Project/app/views/users,  I have the index.html.erb file:

```
<div id="user_list" >

<h1>Listing users</h1>

<table>

    <% @users.each do |user| %>

    <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>" >

        <td class="user_description" >
            <dl>
            <dt><%= user.name %></dt>
            <dt><%= user.surname %></dt>
            <dt><%= user.age %></dt>
            <dt><%= user.date_birth %></dt>
            <dt><%= user.date_of_reg %></dt>
            <dt><%= user.email %></dt>
        </td>
        <td class="list_actions" >
            <%= link_to 'Show', user %><br/>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %><br/>
            <%= link_to 'Destroy', user,
            :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
            :method => :delete %>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>

</table>
</div>
<br />
<%= link_to 'New user', new_user_path %>
```

why is Ruby not loading the CSS file ? Is it placed in the wrong directory?

Comment: If you're just starting to learn rails, you should use at least use 3.1. In Rails 3.1, stylesheets are no longer stored in `public/stylesheets` but use the asset pipeline and are stored under `assets/stylesheets`.

Comment: I just moved the css file over there, and it still doesnt work. Is maybe he filename wrong?

Comment: ok found the error. I had to change   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    :all  %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
to   <%= stylesheet_link_tag   "application"  %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

Comment: any idea why it works now ? lol, does "application" tag means to look in the assets folder?

Answer (score 1):

Since rails 3.1 there is a thing called the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). This will make sure that your css files are packaged into 1 file, and one other file containing all your js files. This will make sure that the initial download is much quicker.

In your `app/assets/stylesheets` is an `application.css` which serves as the manifest. This file will contain a description which css files will need to be included in the complete `application.css`.

This file, by default, contains something like

```
/* 
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

and this means that whatever is inside the `application.css` file itself, plus all other files in the same folder will be included in the final `application.css`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues:

1. **wrong path** - don't put asset files directly into public. the asset pipeline compiles files from `/app/assets/stylesheets` and outputs them to `/public/assets`. So move your css file to `/app/assets/stylesheets` first.
2. **wrong filename** - see the 5th line of your first code example where it says `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    :all  %>`? That's telling the asset pipeline to look for a css file in `/public/assets` named `all.css`. Obviously your css file is not named that. So change that as well and you should be good to go!